# SQL Server deadlock on the same objid

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, database-deadlocks

Occasionally our application sees deadlocks on one particular table. The database is 16 processor SQL Server 2012 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) and the SQLs are generated by hibernate. From the deadlock graph I see that there is a delete SQL in one transaction and an update SQL in the other. What I don't understand from the graph is that the objid of both the owner resource and the requested resource is the same. If it already owns a lock on that record, why would the transaction be requesting a lock on the same object? I read Brad McGehee's article https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/how-to-track-down-deadlocks-using-sql-server-2005-profiler/ and other msdn documentation but they all explain scenarios where the owned resource and requested resource is different. Sorry, this is my first posting on stackoverflow so please let me know if my post does not give sufficient information.

```
    <deadlock-list>
     <deadlock victim="process8fc64dc38">
     <process-list>
       <process id="process8fc64dc38" taskpriority="0" logused="348" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057594042843136 (83d75ea09649)" waittime="3635" ownerId="64693878583" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2015-09-11T12:49:54.470" XDES="0x8e917f838" lockMode="U" schedulerid="16" kpid="1920" status="suspended" spid="98" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2015-09-11T12:49:54.480" lastbatchcompleted="2015-09-11T12:49:54.480" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.480" clientapp="Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver" hostname="TSC-APP" hostpid="0" loginname="atms" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="64693878583" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
       <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="568" sqlhandle="0x020000000336ba1ffcbedac90f190fce2fde4a3bac3cc5e80000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
    update dms_priority_queue set priority=@P0, owner=@P1, active=@P2, start_date=@P3, position=@P4, end_date=@P5, action_type=@P6, audit_date=@P7, message=@P8, beacon=@P9, delay=@P10, submit_time=@P11, audit_user=@P12, priority_key=@P13, associated_type=@P14, associated=@P15, dow_repeat=@P16 where device_id=@P17 and entry_id=@P18     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
    (@P0 int,@P1 nvarchar(4000),@P2 bit,@P3 datetime2,@P4 int,@P5 datetime2,@P6 nvarchar(4000),@P7 datetime2,@P8 nvarchar(4000),@P9 bit,@P10 int,@P11 datetime2,@P12 nvarchar(4000),@P13 nvarchar(4000),@P14 nvarchar(4000),@P15 varchar(8000),@P16 nvarchar(4000),@P17 int,@P18 nvarchar(4000))update dms_priority_queue set priority=@P0, owner=@P1, active=@P2, start_date=@P3, position=@P4, end_date=@P5, action_type=@P6, audit_date=@P7, message=@P8, beacon=@P9, delay=@P10, submit_time=@P11, audit_user=@P12, priority_key=@P13, associated_type=@P14, associated=@P15, dow_repeat=@P16 where device_id=@P17 and entry_id=@P18                                                                                                                                                       </inputbuf>
       </process>
       <process id="process8fc04d498" taskpriority="0" logused="948" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057594042843136 (0c15a51ae59f)" waittime="3631" ownerId="64693878466" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2015-09-11T12:49:54.467" XDES="0x7ac1e03a8" lockMode="X" schedulerid="8" kpid="10364" status="suspended" spid="144" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2015-09-11T12:49:54.487" lastbatchcompleted="2015-09-11T12:49:54.487" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.487" clientapp="Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver" hostname="TSC-APP" hostpid="0" loginname="atms" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="64693878466" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
        <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="56" sqlhandle="0x02000000bd9f3034c4569fe476061660252530233735d0640000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
delete from dms_priority_queue where device_id=@P0 and entry_id=@P1     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
        (@P0 int,@P1 nvarchar(4000))delete from dms_priority_queue where device_id=@P0 and entry_id=@P1                    </inputbuf>
   </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594042843136" dbid="5" objectname="nwatms2.dbo.dms_priority_queue" indexname="pk_dms_priority_queue" id="lock7b664d300" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594042843136">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process8fc04d498" mode="X"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process8fc64dc38" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594042843136" dbid="5" objectname="nwatms2.dbo.dms_priority_queue" indexname="pk_dms_priority_queue" id="lock3533d6280" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594042843136">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process8fc64dc38" mode="X"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process8fc04d498" mode="X" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
  </resource-list>
 </deadlock>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The locks in question (key locks) affect ranges within a table, not the entire table. [See MSDN on Lock Granularity and Hierarchies](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189849(v=sql.105).aspx).

In this case, each of the two processes owns an exclusive lock (`mode=X`) on a single range within `dms_priority_queue`, but is waiting on a lock on an additional range within the same table.

Comment: Thanks. I thought objid was the recordid. I re-read the documentation and realized that objid referred to the table. I read the link you had mentioned and realized that keylock could be a range of values based on the where condition. Need to go figure out how to prevent this deadlock now.

Comment: I just had a look at the table and the where condition in both the SQLs above is the primary key of the table. So when a delete sql is deleting a record based on the primary key, why would it be locking a range of values?

Comment: Note the transaction count. The `delete` and `update` are attempting to acquire the locks they require to execute, but I believe there was something else that executed within the same transaction as the `delete` and `update` that is holding the conflicting locks.

Comment: Thank you so so much! I think I am going to turn on detailed SQL logging and see the other SQLs that are being executed a part of the transaction. I understand the deadlock trace a lot better now!